# How can i uninstall QtCreator 2.6.1 from 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, development, qt-creator, qt5

I downloaded QtCreator 2.6.1 from the official website http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-creator because i'm using ubuntu 12.04. Now i need to uninstall it. How can i do it?

- [64-bit Linux Installer](http://releases.qt-project.org/qtcreator/2.6.1/qt-creator-linux-x86_64-opensource-2.6.1.bin)

Answer (score 4):

Run the QtCreator Maintenance program. If you accepted the default paths in the 2.6.1 installer, it's at /opt/Qt5.0.0/MaintenanceTool . The default option is Remove All Components.

Comment: There is no such program in the path where app is installed.

Comment: Did you install the full SDK or the standalone QtCreator? I think only the SDK gives you the MaintenanceTool. (And did you uncheck any options during the install?) For the standalone, I think you can just remove the directories it setup.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer on modern computers.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Startec I gave it an upvote. Just double click the "maintainance tool"

Answer (score 3):

In the location where application is installed (default location: `/opt/Qt5.0.0/`) is a file named `QtCreatorUninstaller`. Run this executable in the terminal to uninstall QtCreator.

Answer (score 3):

I installed `QtCreator` from the default *.run* file distributed from the website.
`QtCreator` is located on `~/Qt/` directory.

You'll see the `MaintenanceTool` executable there,

1. you have to run that on terminal
2. Login to your Qt Creator account
3. Select appropriate removal option
   --> For me it's remove all components.

[here's how I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik4vz.png)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to open **Ubuntu Software Center** and click on Installed tab and if you can see the  QtCreator in the list then there you will find a button <kbd>Remove</kbd>, the second way is from terminal
`sudo apt-get remove {package-name}`

Comment: Ubuntu Software Center doesn't see QtCreator 2.6.1 neither apt-get remove does the job.

Comment: +1 It worked for me although i used  `sudo apt-get remove qtcreator*` to remove all related to `qtcreator`